# Create a function in the memory to call it later

Tags: c++, function, caching

Ok, my question is probably stupid, but I will regreat not asking it.
I would like to know if it is possible to create a function during program execution and then be able to call it later. This function will not be hard coded because it depends on many initial parameters decided by the program user. The objective would be to avoid calling these parameters, each time we need to call this function and hence, gain execution time and memory. I will give a minimalist example because I believe my question is not so easy to understand just with words.

In this example, I have a `class Parameters` that contain parameters **A1, A2, A3** used to solve an equation. These parameters vary due to initial conditions. The second `class CalculFunction` uses these `Parameters` to solve the equation at the moment **t**. The way it is coded, each time I have to evaluate a new moment **t'**, I have to go through the `Parameters objects` again to solve the equation. However, I would like to store directly a function in the memory, that contains the correct parameters and can be evaluated at **t1, t2** etc.. without requiring to call startCalculation(const double & t, const double & initValue) method again. 
My goal is to construct the function only one time and have in the memory a function `f[i] = initValue * sum( A1[i][j] / A2[i][j] * exp( -A3[i] * t)` where the sum occurs on j. Hence, I just call fi to get results without reconstructing the whole loops on j.

```
class Parameters
{
public:
    Parameters();

    QVector<double> & getA1(){return m_a1;};
    QVector<double> & getA2(){return m_a2;};
    double & getA3(){return m_a3;};


private:
    QVector<double> m_a1;
    QVector<double> m_a2;
    double m_a3;


};

class CalculFunction
{
public:
    CalculFunction(const QVector<Parameters> & allParam): m_parameters(allParam);

    void startCalculation(const double & t, const double & initValue)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_parameters.size(); i++)
        {
            m_results.append(0.);

            for(int j = 0; j < m_parameters[i].getA1().size(); j++)
            {
               m_results[i] += m_parameters[i].getA1()[j] / m_parameters[i].getA2()[j] * exp(- (m_parameters[i].getA3() ) * t );
            }

            m_results[i] *= initValue;
        }
    }

private:
    QVector<Parameters> m_parameters;
    QVector<double> m_results;
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), stored in a [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: I will carefully look at what a lambda is. It might be a working solution. Hence, I will try to adapt my example with lambda to see if what I want is possible.

Comment: No such thing as a stupid question :)

Comment: But do A1, A2, A3 change from t1, to t2, to t3?

Comment: A1, A2 and A3 are not depending on t1, t2, t3 ...etc. That is why I would gain a lot of time if the function f[i] is stored in the memory, and I just need to modify the value of t t have a result. Even farther, if the f[i] can be stored in the memory, they can also be stored in a file so I can generate it once for all ;)

Comment: @froz What sort of time are you expecting to save? I would not expect the run time to be any different, since the calculation still needs to be made. You might save programming time, though, if you pick a good class design.

Comment: Continuing my last thought: you might want to think about what would happen if the parameters were not decided by the program's user, but by the program's writer (i.e. you). Suppose you've hardcoded the parameters. How would that make calculating the function at time `t` any more efficient? Would you not have to loop through your vectors, adding values? What sort of shortcut are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for functor then. Functor is a class that is capable to storing internal states but has the operator() member that acts like a function.

```
class AFunc
{
public:
    AFunc(A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3) : a1(a1), a2(a2), a3(a3) {} 
    T operator()(arguments ...) {
       T t
        ...
       return t;
    }

private:
    A1 a1;
    A2 a2;
    A3 a3;
 };
```

where T is the return type.
You can have as many arguments in the constructor and operator(...) as you need.

You would just call it like

```
AFunc af(a1, a2, a3);

T t = af(arguments ...);
```

in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understand well, I create a functor in which, inside the operator(), I insert the code that was in my method void startCalculation(const double & t, const double & initValue). In this case, each time I call for af(arguments), it will again reconstruct the solution by going through the QVector A1, A2. Hence, the function will be reconstructed each time I call it, right ?

Comment: @froz you can preconstruct some of it in the constructor obviously. But each of your term has different t-dependent which you need to evaluate and sum no matter what.

Comment: ok, I understand. I thought it could be possible to pass one time in the for loop and then using something I don't know in C++, getting function evaluated at t without going back in these loops, just because the function (t) would be stored in the memory, like if I was calling exp(t) or cos(t) ...etc Your solution will make me gain calculation time ?

Answer (score 1):

I would re-envision your `Parameters` class. At the moment, it is a glorified `struct`, some data with getters, but no logic. Instead of simply storing the parameters, you could view it as your function. Put the logic of how to calculate a value at a particular time in this class. If you want it to look like a function call, you can use `operator()`, but you could also use a named member function, perhaps `eval()`. Let's go with the operator for now.

```
class Function // Not the best name, but good enough for now.
{
public:
    Function(QVector<double> param1, QVector<double> param2, double param3) :
        m_a1(std::move(param1)),
        m_a2(std::move(param2)),
        m_a3(param3)
    {}

    // This is what will evaluate your function at a given time. This will not
    // speed up the execution, but it does help improve data encapsulation.        
    double operator()(double t)
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        for(int j = 0; j < m_a1.size(); j++)
        {
            result += m_a1[j] / m_a2()[j] * exp(- m_a3 * t );
        }
        return result;
    }

private:
    const QVector<double> m_a1;  // Add `const` to these if you want to
    const QVector<double> m_a2;  // emphasize that they do not change
    const double m_a3;           // after initialization.
};
```

All that's happened is some logic got shifted into this class. There is no expected savings in execution time. The savings comes when you try to write your other class.

```
class CalculFunction
{
public:
    CalculFunction(const QVector<Function> & allParam): m_parameters(allParam) {}

    void startCalculation(const double & t, const double & initValue)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_parameters.size(); i++)
            m_results.append(m_parameters[i](t) * initValue); // Invoke operator() here
    }

private:
    QVector<Function> m_parameters;
    QVector<double> m_results;
};
```

The overall code is shorter and more organized, optimizing the programmer's time.

Comment: That is a nice improvement of the writting. I will try it and compare the execution time. What is the std::move() benefit in the Function constructor?

Comment: @froz The vector parameters should either be taken by (`const`) reference and given to copy constructors, or be taken by value and given to move constructors. The latter helps if you initialize from temporary vectors. On the other hand, it might not make a measurable difference with `QVector`.